# Set case insensitivity in custom validator

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, ignore-case

I am working with `Fluent Validation` in which I am writing a custom validation that checks that the current value of the property contains any of a list of values like so:

```
IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> IsOfValue<T, TProperty> rule, params TProperty[] validOptions)
{
   return rule
     .Must(validOptions.Contains)
     .WithMessage("Custom Error")
}
```

My issue is... How can I alter the `Must(validOptions.Contains)` so that when the value is of type string, Ignore case?

I can do this easily for variants that are not utilizing lists, but can't figure out the logic to use here.

I know that I need to use either `StringComparer.IgnoreOrdinalCase` or `StringComparison.IgnoreOrdinalCase` depending.

Comment: whats the full signature of that method?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I apologize, but I do not understand what you mean by "signature"

Comment: It is the first line of the code you pasted; it is incomplete.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 The only thing omitted from that code was the line to set the list of `validOptions` to string for the error message. Otherwise, that is/was the full code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to check `TProperty` type, if is `string` you can use

```
string.Contains(x.ToString(),StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

otherwise use your default.

```
IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> IsOfValue<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> rule, params TProperty[] validOptions)
{
    IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> result = rule
                 .Must(validOptions.Contains)
                 .WithMessage("Custom Error");

   if(typeof(TProperty) == typeof(string)){
       string[] vailds = validOptions as string[];
       result = rule
                .Must(x => vailds.Contains(x.ToString(),StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .WithMessage("Custom Error");

   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: No problem :) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specialized version of that generic method, and it would be called instead:

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> IsOfValue<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> rule, params TProperty[] validOptions)
{
    return rule
        .Must(validOptions.Contains)
        .WithMessage("Custom Error");
}

public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> IsOfValue<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> rule, params string[] validOptions) => rule.IsOfValue(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase, validOptions);
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> IsOfValue<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> rule, StringComparer comparer, params string[] validOptions)
{
    return rule
        .Must(x => validOptions.Contains(x, comparer))
        .WithMessage("Custom Error");
}
```